# How to pass value of state variable from one component to a sibling component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to pass state variable from Filter to PaginatedTable component. How to impement it? Maybe I should use redux? (I have no idea how redux works, but I heard it is used to manage state of application)

```
import React from "react";

function CompanyTable(): JSX.Element{

    return <>
        <Filter/>
        <PaginatedTable/>
    </>
}
```

Comment: you can use the CompanyTable's state if you want. no need for redux if the exchange is only between these 2 components

Comment: @Apostolos Hmm, why would I use CompanyTable's state? Filter's state variable receives a value after user's input. If I am not mistaken it is not legit to change a value of a prop variable in child component

Comment: yes and you want to pass it to another component. why use redux since these 2 are inside another component/container? use this container's state in order to pass values.

Comment: you can always of course use redux, that's not wrong or bad, but since the state is shared between these 2 i guess there is no need for redux here. my opinion though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux seems like overkill for this simple use case, particularly if you have to learn redux first.

I assume you have a state variable and a function to set the state variable in your `Filter` component, and you want the value to be available in your `PaginatedTable` component. Using hooks, I would do it this way

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CompanyTable(): JSX.Element{
    const [yourVariable, setYourVariable] = useState(yourVariablesInitialState)
    return <>
        <Filter setYourVariable={setYourVariable}/>
        <PaginatedTable yourVariable={yourVariable}/>
    </>
}
```

You can now call `props.setYourVariable` in your `Filter` component and the value you pass will be available in your `PaginatedTable` component. And you no longer need to have the variable in the `Filter` component's state. If you also want to have it there, you can pass it down as a prop as with `PaginatedTable`. You should change the names from my example as those names are pretty bad.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I need

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to go about it, you can decide based upon your needs.
If you have a very basic application, then passing the state as props can help.

If you have an application like a complex to-do list or anything of that scale you can use context API.

Or, If you have a very large application like an e-commerce website where you have to share many states or your states are dynamic in nature then you can use redux.

Here are the links for your reference.

1. [Passing states as props](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/passing-state-of-parent-to-child-component-as-props)
2. [Managing state as Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
3. [Managing state with Redux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-state-in-react-with-redux)